# Are there any known limitations when running GRPC after setting a network namespace in Golang?

Tags: go, grpc

I'm experiencing a problem to communicate between GRPC client and server after switching network namespace in my Golang project. To zoom in on this issue, I modified the  GRPC example program Hello World accordingly with the same problem as a result. Are there any known limitations when using GRPC after switching namespace in a golang application?

I have read  about issues related to switching namespace in Golang, but I guess it depends on the GRPC behaviour if this could lead to a problem or not.

1. Does the GRPC client spawn any additional goroutines? Such a goroutine would not necessarily execute in the same namespace as the original goroutine locked the thread due to the namespace switch.
2. I assume that the GRPC server spawns goroutines for each client, but does it create a socket in the original goroutine before a new is spawned? This question is also related to that the spawned goroutines doesn't have to execute in the same namespace as where grpc.Serve() was called (namespace switch requires runtime.LockOSThread()).

Communication works in case server and client are started in matching namespaces (ip netns exec...), but fails in case namespace switch is performed internally in the client. Communication also works when namespace switch is performed internally in the server, so the problem should be in the client.

greeter_client/main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    pb "grpctest/helloworld/helloworld"

    "github.com/vishvananda/netns"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

const (
    defaultName    = "world"
    defaultAddress = "localhost:50051"
    nsEnv          = "NAMESPACE"
    addressEnv     = "ADDRESS"
    blockEnv       = "DIALBLOCK"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("* Client thread id before runtime.LockOSThread(): %d\n", syscall.Gettid())
    runtime.LockOSThread()
    defer runtime.UnlockOSThread()
    fmt.Printf("* Client thread id after runtime.LockOSThread(): %d\n", syscall.Gettid())

    var dialOpts []grpc.DialOption
    dialOpts = append(dialOpts, grpc.WithInsecure())
    _, ok := os.LookupEnv(blockEnv)
    if ok == true {
        dialOpts = append(dialOpts, grpc.WithBlock())
        fmt.Printf("* Dial in blocked mode\n")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("* Dial in unblocked mode\n")
    }

    address, ok := os.LookupEnv(addressEnv)
    if ok == false {
        address = defaultAddress
    }

    fmt.Printf("* Talk to server at %s\n", address)

    var origns netns.NsHandle
    namespace, ok := os.LookupEnv(nsEnv)
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf("* Switch namespace to %s\n", namespace)
        origns, err := netns.Get()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("failed to get current namespace")
        }

        defer origns.Close()
        newns, err := netns.GetFromName(namespace)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to get new namespace: %s", namespace)
        }

        err = netns.Set(newns)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to set new namespace: %s", namespace)
        }

        defer newns.Close()
    }

    fmt.Printf("* Client thread id before grpc.Dial(): %d\n", syscall.Gettid())
    // Set up a connection to the server.
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, dialOpts...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    fmt.Printf("* Client thread id before pb.NewGreeterClient(): %d\n", syscall.Gettid())
    c := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)
    fmt.Printf("* Client thread id after pb.NewGreeterClient(): %d\n", syscall.Gettid())

    // Contact the server and print out its response.
    name := defaultName
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        name = os.Args[1]
    }

    r, err := c.SayHello(context.Background(), &pb.HelloRequest{Name: name})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("could not greet: %v", err)
        select {}
        log.Fatalf("could not greet: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("* Client thread id after c.SayHello(): %d\n", syscall.Gettid())

    log.Printf("Greeting: %s", r.Message)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    if namespace != "" {
        netns.Set(origns)
    }

    fmt.Printf("* Client thread id at exit: %d\n", syscall.Gettid())
}
```

greeter_server/main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "syscall"

    pb "grpctest/helloworld/helloworld"

    "github.com/vishvananda/netns"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/reflection"
)

const (
    port  = ":50051"
    nsEnv = "NAMESPACE"
)

// server is used to implement helloworld.GreeterServer.
type server struct{}

// SayHello implements helloworld.GreeterServer
func (s *server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    fmt.Printf("* RPC call server thread id: %d\n", syscall.Gettid())
    return &pb.HelloReply{Message: "Hello " + in.Name}, nil
}

func main() {
    runtime.LockOSThread()
    defer runtime.UnlockOSThread()
    var origns netns.NsHandle

    namespace := os.Getenv(nsEnv)
    if namespace != "" {
        fmt.Printf("* Switch namespace to %s\n", namespace)
        origns, err := netns.Get()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("failed to get current namespace")
        }

        defer origns.Close()
        newns, err := netns.GetFromName(namespace)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to get new namespace: %s", namespace)
        }

        err = netns.Set(newns)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to set new namespace: %s", namespace)
        }

        defer newns.Close()
    }

    fmt.Printf("* Main server thread id: %d\n", syscall.Gettid())
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
    // Register reflection service on gRPC server.
    reflection.Register(s)

    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }

    if namespace != "" {
        netns.Set(origns)
    }

    fmt.Printf("* Main server exits (thread id: %d)\n", syscall.Gettid())
}
```

Comment: This use case looks very strange. Could you please provide a little more information about why you need it?

Comment: What's strange about switching namespace. In case you can't start your application in the correct namespace, you will have to switch in order to access the server. In case you need to access servers running in different namespaces, you can't solve the problem by starting the application in one of these namespaces. The example just illustrates the problem.

Comment: 1. What is a reason you don't know the appropriate network namespace at the application startup? 2. Accessing servers in different namespace looks strange as well. From my point of view, for the remote access servers must be distinguished via endpoints (`host:port`). Remote client should not know about sever's machine local network settings. So the use case is still not clear.

Comment: 1. Who said I don't know the network namespaces at startup? I know all three of them (including default network namespace).
2. Not sure I understand what you mean, but I think it is more important to focus on the GRPC problem rather than the use case. However, there's nothing strange with separating different types of network traffic on different networks (for instance OAM, backhaul, fronthaul). I don't think it's strange to isolate those networks using network namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem where the netns kept switching back to the original namespace on every new goroutine regardless of locking OS threads or not.

I found that as long as the server is started in the correct netns (I gave up trying to do this programmatically and just spawned the server proc via `exec.Command`), you just have to set a custom dialer for the GRPC client to restore the goroutine during the connection to the right netns:

```
dialOpts = append(dialOpts, grpc.WithDialer(func(addr string, timeout time.Duration) (net.Conn, error) {
        netns.Set(newns)
        return net.DialTimeout("tcp", addr, timeout)
    }))
```

Comment: Yes, a custom dialer was the solution. I gave up on stack overflow and asked the GRPC developers instead, since they understood the usecase and showed interest in finding a solution.